# How can I prevent CSS pseudo elements from disappearing during an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my (simplified) situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/qFhaq/

Clicking the button launches an animation that expands the height of the div. While the div is expanding, the `:after` pseudo-element (containing the text 'look') disappears and then reappears at the end of the animation.

Is there a way to prevent the pseudo-element from disappearing, so that it's visible throughout the animation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add "overflow" CSS rule to #main and set it to "visible !important;"

```
#main{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why it works when `!important` is included and doesn't work when it's excluded?

Comment: jQuery adds inline style "overflow:hidden" to elements while animating them . The :after element exists outside of its parent (#main)  and it will be hidden. So we just add "overflow:visible !important;" to the css to override inline style added by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite it that it used CSS3 transition:

**JS (for fast, for better you can change it to vanilla js):**

```
$(function(){
    $("#clicky").click(function(){
        $("#main").addClass('animate');
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#main{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s linear;
}

#main:after{
    content: "look";
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 210px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#main.animate{
    height: 500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qFhaq/1/

Comment: Is there a jQuery solution? The situation I posted above is extremely simplified, I actually have a much more complex animation and converting it to CSS is impractical.

Comment: Well doesn't know it.